# Using PHP in Android scripting

Tags: php, android

I have a question to ask, the question is that can we script the app for android by using php,javascript etc.. any of the web development programming languages. Instead of java. If we can please then help me out and please also provide the download link of these programming languages JDK's so can write my own programe using it :D

Thank you.
Javed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) to create Android Application to use JAVASCRIPT, HTML. You can use PHP as well, but then you will have to host your application on a webserver and application will run from your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can build android app using HTML, CSS, Javascript with [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) or [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/titanium/).
However, you still need to host your PHP in a webserver.

Comment: Host? You mean xamp or wamp? That i uses to test websites. btw if i want to test my app how can i have an ammulator?